# Assigning a Variable to Another Variable in a Union in C

Tags: c, variables, structure, unions, mplab

I am working on a project in MPLAB X IDE 3.60. There some union/structure definitions in it. They are used to drive 7 segment LCD.

I can not pass a variable into another one by using its name. It assigns a random value instead. However, I can assign the value itself to the related variable and LCD works perfectly.

main.c

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 40000000
#if defined(__XC)
    #include <xc.h>        /* XC8 General Include File */
#elif defined(HI_TECH_C)
    #include <htc.h>       /* HiTech General Include File */
#elif defined(__18CXX)
    #include <p18cxxx.h>   /* C18 General Include File */
#endif

#if defined(__XC) || defined(HI_TECH_C)

#include <stdint.h>        /* For uint8_t definition */
#include <stdbool.h>       /* For true/false definition */
#endif

#include "system.h"        /* System funct/params, like osc/peripheral config */
#include "user.h"          /* User funct/params, such as InitApp */
#include "lcd_driver.h"

//CONFIG
#pragma config SOSCSEL = DIG
#pragma config FOSC = HS1       // Oscillator (HS oscillator (Medium power, 4 MHz - 16 MHz))
#pragma config PLLCFG = ON      // PLL x4 Enable bit (Enabled)
#pragma config FCMEN = OFF      // Fail-Safe Clock Monitor (Disabled)
#pragma config IESO = OFF       // Internal External Oscillator Switch Over Mode (Disabled)



void main(void)
{
    /* Configure the oscillator for the device */
    ConfigureOscillator();
    //Variables 

    ANCON2 = 0x00;
    CCP6OD = 0; // RG3, comparator disabled.
    OSCCONbits.SCS = 0;


    LcdInit();
    LCD_7SEG();
    LCD_Update();

    while(1)
    {

    } 
}
```

lcd_driver.c

```
#include <xc.h>

#include "lcd_driver.h"
#include "defines.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>


volatile StructLCD      MediumLCDBuffer; // Not used yet
volatile StructLCD      MediumLCD @0xF66;

volatile UDigit UpdatedDigit;


void LcdInit(void)
{
    // Init ports function for LCD driver
    LCDSE0bits.SE00 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE01 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE02 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE03 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE04 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE05 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE06 = 1;
    LCDSE0bits.SE07 = 1;

    LCDSE1bits.SE08 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE09 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE10 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE11 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE12 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE13 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE14 = 1;
    LCDSE1bits.SE15 = 1;

    LCDSE2bits.SE18 = 1;
    LCDSE2bits.SE19 = 1;
    LCDSE2bits.SE20 = 1;
    LCDSE2bits.SE21 = 1;
    LCDSE2bits.SE22 = 1;
    LCDSE2bits.SE23 = 1;

    LCDSE3bits.SE24 = 1;
    LCDSE3bits.SE25 = 1;
    LCDSE3bits.SE26 = 1; 
    LCDSE3bits.SE29 = 1;
    LCDSE3bits.SE29 = 1;
    LCDSE3bits.SE30 = 1;

    // Reference ladder interval control
    LCDRLbits.LRLAT0 = 1;
    LCDRLbits.LRLAT1 = 1;
    LCDRLbits.LRLAT2 = 1;

    // Reference ladder A Power Control
    LCDRLbits.LRLAP0 = 1;
    LCDRLbits.LRLAP1 = 1;

    // Reference ladder B Power Control
    LCDRLbits.LRLBP0 = 1;
    LCDRLbits.LRLBP1 = 1;

    // Select internal bias
    LCDREFbits.VLCD1PE = 0;
    LCDREFbits.VLCD2PE = 0;
    LCDREFbits.VLCD3PE = 0;

    // Enable internal reference
    LCDREFbits.LCDIRE = 1;

    // Select internal reference source (VDD)
    LCDREFbits.LCDIRS = 0;

    // Select LCD contrast (0 = Max contrast, 7 = min contrast)
    LCDREFbits.LCDCST0 = 1;
    LCDREFbits.LCDCST1 = 0;
    LCDREFbits.LCDCST2 = 0;

    /* LCDCON register */
    LCDCONbits.LCDEN = 1; //Enable LCD Module
    LCDCONbits.SLPEN = 0;
    LCDCONbits.WERR = 0;
    LCDCONbits.CS = 0; // (Fosc/4)/8192))
    LCDCONbits.LMUX = 3; // <1:0> 1/4 COM, 1/3 BIAS 


    /* LCDPS register  */
    LCDPSbits.WFT = 0; // Type-A Waveform Selection.
    LCDPSbits.BIASMD = 0;
    LCDPSbits.LCDA = 1;
    LCDPSbits.WA = 0;
    // LCD prescaler bits
    LCDPSbits.LP0 = 1;
    LCDPSbits.LP1 = 1;
    LCDPSbits.LP2 = 0; // 1:4
    LCDPSbits.LP3 = 0;
}

void LCD_7SEG(void)
{         
    unsigned char buffer = 0x12; // assign a value
    //printf("%u", (unsigned char) buffer); // Does not work without this line, It assigns random value instead of buffer value
    UpdatedDigit.DigitChar = buffer;        
}

void LCD_Update(void)
{        
    MediumLCD.Seg10A = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_A;   MediumLCD.Seg10B = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_B;
    MediumLCD.Seg10C = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_C;   MediumLCD.Seg10D = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_D;
    MediumLCD.Seg10E = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_E;   MediumLCD.Seg10F = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_F;
    MediumLCD.Seg10G = UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_G;

}
```

lcd_driver.h

```
#ifndef LCD_DRIVER_H
#define LCD_DRIVER_H

#ifdef  __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef  __cplusplus
}
#endif  


typedef struct 
{
    // -- COM 3 (LCD)-- //)         PIC(No) |   LCD(no))
    unsigned char ECOLOWER      :1; //Seg0      LCD1
    unsigned char Seg5D         :1; //Seg1      LCD2
    unsigned char DP5           :1; //Seg2      LCD3
    unsigned char Seg6D         :1; //Seg3      LCD4
    unsigned char DP6           :1; //Seg4      LCD5
    unsigned char Seg7D         :1; //Seg5      LCD6
    unsigned char DEGLOWER      :1; //Seg6      LCD7
    unsigned char ECOUPPER      :1; //Seg7      LCD8    (LCD9 -> SEG30)

    unsigned char DP7           :1; //Seg8      LCD10
    unsigned char Seg9D         :1; //Seg9      LCD11
    unsigned char DP8           :1; //Seg10     LCD12
    unsigned char Seg10D        :1; //Seg11     LCD13   (LCD14 -> SEG29)
    unsigned char kW            :1; //Seg12     LCD15
    unsigned char BarFrame_09   :1; //Seg13     LCD16
    unsigned char BarGraph_I5   :1; //Seg14     LCD17
    unsigned char BarFrame_I5   :1; //Seg15     LCD18    

    unsigned char Dummy1        :1; //Seg16     Disabled!
    unsigned char Dummy2        :1; //Seg17     Disabled!
    unsigned char Seg4B         :1; //Seg18     LCD19
    unsigned char Seg4A         :1; //Seg19     LCD20
    unsigned char Seg3B         :1; //Seg20     LCD21
    unsigned char Seg3A         :1; //Seg21     LCD22
    unsigned char Seg2B         :1; //Seg22     LCD23
    unsigned char Seg2A         :1; //Seg23     LCD24

    unsigned char Seg1B         :1; //Seg24     LCD25
    unsigned char Seg1A         :1; //Seg25     LCD26
    unsigned char Service       :1; //Seg26     LCD27
    unsigned char Dummy3        :1; //Seg27     Disabled
    unsigned char Dummy4        :1; //Seg28     Disabled
    unsigned char DummyNC       :1; //Seg29     LCD14
    unsigned char Seg8D         :1; //Seg30     LCD9
    unsigned char Dummy5        :1; //Seg31     Disabled

    unsigned char Dummy6        :8; //LCDDATA4 not available
    unsigned char Dummy7        :8; //LCDDATA5 not available

    // -- COM 2 (LCD)-- //)         PIC(No) |   LCD(no))
    unsigned char COD           :1; //Seg0      LCD1
    unsigned char Seg5E         :1; //Seg1      LCD2
    unsigned char Seg5C         :1; //Seg2      LCD3
    unsigned char Seg6E         :1; //Seg3      LCD4
    unsigned char Seg6C         :1; //Seg4      LCD5
    unsigned char Seg7E         :1; //Seg5      LCD6
    unsigned char Seg7C         :1; //Seg6      LCD7
    unsigned char VAL           :1; //Seg7      LCD8    (LCD9 -> SEG30)

    unsigned char Seg8C         :1; //Seg8      LCD10
    unsigned char Seg9E         :1; //Seg9      LCD11
    unsigned char Seg9C         :1; //Seg10     LCD12
    unsigned char Seg10E        :1; //Seg11     LCD13   (LCD14 -> SEG29)
    unsigned char Lmin          :1; //Seg12     LCD15
    unsigned char BarFrame_I9   :1; //Seg13     LCD16
    unsigned char BarFrame_I6   :1; //Seg14     LCD17
    unsigned char BarGraph_I6   :1; //Seg15     LCD18    

    unsigned char Dummy8        :1; //Seg16     Disabled!
    unsigned char Dummy9        :1; //Seg17     Disabled!
    unsigned char Seg4G         :1; //Seg18     LCD19
    unsigned char Seg4F         :1; //Seg19     LCD20
    unsigned char Seg3G         :1; //Seg20     LCD21
    unsigned char Seg3F         :1; //Seg21     LCD22
    unsigned char Seg2G         :1; //Seg22     LCD23
    unsigned char Seg2F         :1; //Seg23     LCD24

    unsigned char Seg1G         :1; //Seg24     LCD25
    unsigned char Seg1F         :1; //Seg25     LCD26
    unsigned char WaterDrop     :1; //Seg26     LCD27
    unsigned char Dummy10       :1; //Seg27     Disabled
    unsigned char Dummy11       :1; //Seg28     Disabled
    unsigned char Seg10C        :1; //Seg29     LCD14
    unsigned char Seg8E         :1; //Seg30     LCD9
    unsigned char Dummy12       :1; //Seg31     Disabled

    unsigned char Dummy13       :8; //LCDDATA10 not available
    unsigned char Dummy14       :8; //LCDDATA11 not available

    // -- COM 1 (LCD)-- //)         PIC(No) |   LCD(no)
    unsigned char TAP           :1; //Seg0      LCD1
    unsigned char Seg5F         :1; //Seg1      LCD2
    unsigned char Seg5G         :1; //Seg2      LCD3
    unsigned char Seg6F         :1; //Seg3      LCD4
    unsigned char Seg6G         :1; //Seg4      LCD5
    unsigned char Seg7F         :1; //Seg5      LCD6
    unsigned char Seg7G         :1; //Seg6      LCD7
    unsigned char Radiator      :1; //Seg7      LCD8    (LCD9 -> SEG30)

    unsigned char Seg8G         :1; //Seg8      LCD10
    unsigned char Seg9F         :1; //Seg9      LCD11
    unsigned char Seg9G         :1; //Seg10     LCD12
    unsigned char Seg10F        :1; //Seg11     LCD13   (LCD14 -> SEG29)
    unsigned char RPM           :1; //Seg12     LCD15
    unsigned char Flame         :1; //Seg13     LCD16
    unsigned char BarGraph_I7    :1; //Seg14     LCD17
    unsigned char BarFrame_I7   :1; //Seg15     LCD18    

    unsigned char Dummy15       :1; //Seg16     Disabled!
    unsigned char Dummy16       :1; //Seg17     Disabled!
    unsigned char Seg4C         :1; //Seg18     LCD19
    unsigned char Seg4E         :1; //Seg19     LCD20
    unsigned char Seg3C         :1; //Seg20     LCD21
    unsigned char Seg3E         :1; //Seg21     LCD22
    unsigned char Seg2C         :1; //Seg22     LCD23
    unsigned char Seg2E         :1; //Seg23     LCD24

    unsigned char Seg1C         :1; //Seg24     LCD25
    unsigned char Seg1E         :1; //Seg25     LCD26
    unsigned char Phone         :1; //Seg26     LCD27
    unsigned char Dummy17       :1; //Seg27     Disabled
    unsigned char Dummy18       :1; //Seg28     Disabled
    unsigned char Seg10G        :1; //Seg29     LCD14
    unsigned char Seg8F         :1; //Seg30     LCD9
    unsigned char Dummy19        :1; //Seg31     Disabled

    unsigned char Dummy20       :8; //LCDDATA16 not available
    unsigned char Dummy21       :8; //LCDDATA17 not available

    // -- COM 0 (LCD)-- //)         PIC(No) |   LCD(No))
    unsigned char Line          :1; //Seg0      LCD1
    unsigned char Seg5A         :1; //Seg1      LCD2
    unsigned char Seg5B         :1; //Seg2      LCD3
    unsigned char Seg6A         :1; //Seg3      LCD4
    unsigned char Seg6B         :1; //Seg4      LCD5
    unsigned char Seg7A         :1; //Seg5      LCD6
    unsigned char Seg7B         :1; //Seg6      LCD7
    unsigned char Dummy22       :1; //Seg7      LCD8    (LCD9 -> SEG30)

    unsigned char Seg8B         :1; //Seg8      LCD10
    unsigned char Seg9A         :1; //Seg9      LCD11
    unsigned char Seg9B         :1; //Seg10     LCD12
    unsigned char Seg10A        :1; //Seg11     LCD13   (LCD14 -> SEG29)
    unsigned char DEGUPPER      :1; //Seg12     LCD15
    unsigned char Dummy23       :1; //Seg13     LCD16
    unsigned char BarFrame_I8   :1; //Seg14     LCD17
    unsigned char BarGraph_I8   :1; //Seg15     LCD18    

    unsigned char Dummy24       :1; //Seg16     Disabled!
    unsigned char Dummy25       :1; //Seg17     Disabled!
    unsigned char BAR           :1; //Seg18     LCD19
    unsigned char Seg4D         :1; //Seg19     LCD20
    unsigned char DP4           :1; //Seg20     LCD21
    unsigned char Seg3D         :1; //Seg21     LCD22
    unsigned char DP2           :1; //Seg22     LCD23
    unsigned char Seg2D         :1; //Seg23     LCD24

    unsigned char DP1           :1; //Seg24     LCD25
    unsigned char Seg1D         :1; //Seg25     LCD26
    unsigned char DP3           :1; //Seg26     LCD27
    unsigned char Dummy26       :1; //Seg27     Disabled
    unsigned char Dummy27       :1; //Seg28     Disabled
    unsigned char Seg10B        :1; //Seg29     LCD14
    unsigned char Seg8A         :1; //Seg30     LCD9
    unsigned char Dummy28       :1; //Seg31     Disabled

    unsigned char Dummy29       :8; //LCDDATA22 not available
    unsigned char Dummy30       :8; //LCDDATA23 not available
} StructLCD;

typedef struct 
{
    unsigned char SEG_A :1;
    unsigned char SEG_B :1;
    unsigned char SEG_C :1;
    unsigned char SEG_D :1;
    unsigned char SEG_E :1;
    unsigned char SEG_F :1;
    unsigned char SEG_G :1;
    unsigned char NONE  :1;   
}DGSeg;

typedef union 
{
    unsigned char DigitChar;
    DGSeg DigitBit;   
}UDigit;

extern volatile StructLCD MediumLCD;
extern volatile UDigit UpdatedDigit;

void LcdInit(void);
void LCD_7SEG(void);
void LCD_Update(void);

#endif  /* LCD_DRIVER_H */
```

Edit : Adding printf lines between the variable definitions unexpectedly works. If I comment these lines out, the problem persists. This behaviour still does not make sense to me.

Edit2 : Full Code added.

```
void LCD_7SEG(void)
{
    unsigned char buffer= 0x11; // assign a value
    printf("%d\n", buffer);
    UpdatedDigit.DigitChar = buffer; // the value is passed successfully, LCD shows SEG_A and SEGE as expected.
    printf("%d\n", UpdatedDigit.DigitChar);
```

Edit 3 : definition of unsigned char is added.

```
<stdint.h>
#ifndef uint8_t
typedef unsigned char uint8_t;
#define uint8_t uint8_t
#define UINT8_MAX (255)
#endif
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make clear in your code snippets what works and what does not work instead of describing your code.

Comment: It smells like undefined behavior...

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: How do you know that the value is wrong?

Comment: @4386427 This code drives an LCD  which includes 7 segments display in it.  0xFF draws "8" on the screen for example. Each bit presents a segment. (8th one is not used). I see undefined symbols on the screen if i try to pass a variable to another. (else, I do see the right one if I pass the value directly )

Comment: How do you connect the variable `UpdatedDigit` to your HW register? I guess that's where your problem is.

Comment: Work for me, http://rextester.com/FVLQ13059, AFAIK this should not be undefined behavior.

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you for your answer but you directly assigned 0xFF value into the structure. What I can not do is assigning 0xFF to an unsigned char first then passing it to structure.

Comment: @4386427 After updating UpdatedDigit, I use the "DigitBit" (like UpdatedDigit.DigitBit.SEG_A ) to update another structre one by one.

Comment: Works for me. Look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: Does UpdatedDigit.DigitChar = (unsigned char) 0xFF work?

Comment: @Stargateur Thank you for your feed-back. I have read the link you have sent and tried to edit my question according to it. Can you please check it and tell me if it is still not proper.

Comment: Perhaps the call to `LCD_7SEG()` gets optimised away?

Comment: @HardikSanghvi: Why? There is not difference between 255 and 0xff?

Comment: @Stargateur FULL code is added.

Comment: I think you do something wrong with the definition of `StructLCD` double check your bit field, without documentation it impossible to know if you fail somewhere, Are you sure this work with `0xFF` (when use printf) too ? If union not working try by hand with bit operator. Note: char is not mandatory to be 8 bit type, use uint8_t ;).

Comment: @Stargateur I have already tested all segments one by one via StructLCD. 8-bit stands for 7 segment of display. (8th one is dummy). 0xFF is randomly chosed by me just to see if it drives all segments (draws "8"). Any other value can be chosen to test if the works or not(I tried any other values too), it is not the case here. I have checked <stdint.h> file and "unsigned char" is defined as uint8_t already. (See the updated question)

Comment: @CuriousPuppy You misunderstand it's uint8_t who is typedef as unsigned char. Anyway, I don't know why this happen.

Comment: Could it be som kind of timing issue? Also, ask your compiler to produce assembly output and compare working vs non-working. Running under debugger would be even better, if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add

```
void LCD_Set(int value)
{         
  UpdatedDigit.DigitChar = value;
}
```

Modify

```
void LCD_7SEG(void)
{         
  LCD_Set(0xff);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The problem exists. I see only 2 random digits are driven. Despite it is supposed to drive all of them since the value is 0xFF.

Comment: @CuriousPuppy: Try `... = (int) buffer;`.

Comment: It works but why, I would like to know the reason behind it since unsigned char is defined as uint8_t why do I have to put "(int)" instruction in front of the variable again ?

Note : Can you also update your answer since I marked it as accepted.

Comment: What does `sizeof UpdatedDigit` give you?

Comment: "*unsigned char is defined as uint8_t*" no, it's the other way round. `uint8_t`  is defined a `unsigned char`. You misread the related `typedef`.

Comment: Yes, I have realised it is the other way around. I will check sizeof the variable tomorrow. I cant reach it now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162565/discussion-between-curiouspuppy-and-alk).

Comment: @CuriousPuppy: Please exactly which compiler are you using?

Comment: Compiler is XC8 v1.45. After a long discussion the problem is solved by changing the definition of DGSeg structure from "unsigned char" to "unsigned int". It is believed that the compiler bug ( or how you call it) caused this problem.